# dropdown menu bootstrap 3x not working on production mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know, but i'm going crazy!!

I am using this template: http://usman.it/themes/charisma/ in client side. Server side is in ASP.NET MVC4... But I think this is not important! (In this moment, I think!!)

Can you see the dropdown menu with logged user in top right? In my application is exactly the same thing. When I run the app in localhost, everything works with no problem. If I publish the app to production, something wrong is happening and I dont know what. **The dropdown menu isn't openning**!!
I click, click, click, click, click, click and nothing!!!

**The first question is:**
 - Do you have all the scripts in production? Yes, I have. (jquery.js, bootstrap.js, etc).

I post some HTML code (.cshtml):

```
           <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">@SecurityContext.User.RealName</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    @if (@SecurityContext.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Seguranca/DetailsUtilizador/"+SecurityContext.User.UserID)">@Localization.Labels.LabelField.PROFILE</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Login/Logout")">@Localization.Labels.LabelField.LOGOUT</a></li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Login/Index")">@Localization.Labels.LabelField.LOGIN</a></li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Do you have any idea what's going on?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Any console errors??

Comment: Can we see the live site?

Comment: No. There are no console errors!!
No because it needs a certificate.. :/

Comment: same issue there is no console errors but line is not working